# report error 404 by email with last accessed URL

Tags: php, jquery, email, http-status-code-404, http-referer

I'm making a page 404 with button for user report that site have a problem. The idea is when user click on button, I receive a email with information of the last page accessed...

The problem is that I'm using the php variable '$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']' and this ever return a null value. I found this question ([In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)) and I came to the conclusion that this variable is not the solution.

This is my .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/erro.php
#ErrorDocument 404 /erro.php #this doesnt work... redirect doesnt work
```

On page erro.php I have code with function email that are working without problem, but I need some manner to take last accessed page that generate error.

On page erro.php I'm trying use:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // return null value
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // return page http://example.com/erro.php
```

I try use alternative with jQuery (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2415645/2761794):

On page erro.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var referrer =  document.referrer;
    alert(referrer); // return null value
});
```

Some suggestion to take last accessed URL on page erro.php for send by email?

Comment: Really doesn't make sense to have users report errors. They are more likely to hit their back button. Use your errors logs on server

Comment: I can't see logs, where I work I have to manage many sites and make more sites every day, so it's not feasible to stare logs.

Comment: Set up cron jobs to read the logs then

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but right now that's not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are willing to work with `mod_rewrite` anyway and have `PHP` there is a slightly different approach.

First you could detect for a request that is for a file or directory that is not there and pass that to the `PHP` script with a rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^(.*) /erro.php?error_path=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Depending on your exact setup you may need to tweak that last line perhaps to

```
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://example.com/erro.php?error_path=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I find that `mod_rewrite` is somewhat akin to voodoo and can sometimes need a little "try it out and see what works".

Then in your `erro.php` file:

```
<?php
    $badfile = $_GET['error_path']; // the URL that 404'd
    http_response_code(404); // send the 404 header code
    // ... your other code
```

The end result for the visitor should be almost the same but you would have access to the data you need.

- Much of the rewrite directive came from this question: [htaccess errordocument 404 and pass url to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467935/htaccess-errordocument-404-and-pass-url-to-path)
- For more on setting response codes in php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php
- `mod_rewrite` cheat sheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/
- The official doc on `mod_rewrite`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html